# What is the origin of the word "Impression" in the Internet advertising term "Cost-Per-Impression" (CPM)

Tags: etymology

In Internet advertising jargon, an "impression" is defined [by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_per_impression) as

> the display of an ad to a user while viewing a web page.

The word is most often used in the term Cost-per-Impression (CPM), the amount of money an advertiser spends for every 1000 views.

According to [Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impression), "impression" is defined as

> the first and immediate effect on an experience or perception of the mind

What does the word "impression" have to do with Internet Advertising?

Who coined the term, and how did it come about?

Comment: Use a better dictionary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a continuation of usage from the legacy (print) advertising. An impression is a single publication of an advertisement, derived from the platen making an impression on paper in the letter press system.

It is not related to the impression it makes on the viewer/ user/ potential customer.

Comment: "Not related to the impression it makes on the viewer..."? Except that this is *exactly* how it is used today. I think the OP wants to know when the transference occurred.

Comment: @Robusto: If a transference occurred, it looks like it happened a [LONG](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=impression) time ago. Apparently, the word has been used in both senses for centuries. I like how Kris quickly and astutely pointed out that, in advertising jargon, the word is related to the media, not the mind.

Comment: @J.R. Then what does it mean to talk about "viewer/reader impressions" if not that? Surely we're not talking about printing presses and platens at this point.

Comment: @Robusto: I beleive that's exactly what we're talking about. Not figurative printing presses, obviously, but the term is a carryover word – much like, say, "upper case."

Comment: A viewer impression is a unit of measurenent: one impression viewed (multipled) by one viewer. Think 'eyeballs'.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, exactly like 'upper case'. Most do not know the association with wooden type cases in two-tier.

Comment: @kris, thanks for your response, although if the answer was 'obvious,' to me, I would not have asked the question. Assume that what's obvious for one person may not be to another.

Comment: @Katelyn, no need at all to be offended, the word is certainly not with reference to anyone. We always use it to mean something is easily inferable for **me**. And yes, my exposure to the print media right from the hand-composing days did help me see the point a bit easily.

Comment: @katelyn Edited. Hope you like it now.

Comment: @Kris: Most people aren't aware of that association?  Really?  I thought it was rather 'obvious' ;^)

Comment: @katelyn nice to be of help and you're welcome. Do contribute more to the ELU knowledge base!

Answer (score 2):

There is an unfortunate error in the original question. "Cost Per Impression" is not "CPM", as if "M" is a phonetic abbreviation for "impression". The "M" is "thousand" from the Roman Numeral, which long predates the use of "K" (Kilo) for "thousand" so "CPM" is "Cost Per Thousand (impressions)", where the "impressions" implied.

In advertising, CPM is often the billing unit, CPI is rarely if ever used, and this applies to print as well as internet. If you book an ad campaign for your car or scotch to be in every Conde-Nast publication in the US, your billing will be based on the total number of magazines sold (or maybe printed, as in the original meaning of "impression", impressing the image onto paper), regardless of the circulation of the individual magazine titles.